# Question related to Discrete Markov Chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a dual core processor which operates using a cache memory.
Two processes cannot simultaneously access the cache i.e. if a process is
accessing the cache and another process tries to access it, there is a conflict and
the latter must wait for the former to finish accessing.
Assume one process is running on each of the two cores and the probabilities of
accessing the cache in any time slot are p1 and p2 respectively for the two
processes. Also, the time spent to fetch the cache contents is exactly one time
slot. You can assume that all requests made are independent of each other and no
more retrieval requests can be generated by a process if a previous request is yet
to be completed. Model the above system using a DTMC and give the transition matrix.

How do I approach this problem? I am unsure of what the states should be.

Comment: Can you be more precise? When both processes aren't using the cache and then they try to use the cache at the same time, what happens? Maybe give an example of 10 or so time steps.

Comment: @TkiDeneb Ok. Let me edit it. So far I'm only given this info.